# Create paginated Drupal form. (Drupal 6)

Tags: php, drupal

I am trying to create a form which provide a checkbox element on each row. Problem is that I have 2000 rows which takes some time to load and also it is not easy to navigate through whole list.

Is there a way to create some kind of pagination in Drupal form ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in pagination of field values within the context of a larger form that I'm aware of. Instead, you'd probably want to consider a Javascript solution, where you load all 2000 form values, but you use JS and CSS to hide all but the first page. Then you create Javascript forward/back and page links which dynamically hide the first "page" of checkboxes and load the page in question.

The reason I recommend this, instead of an AJAX request that loads only the first 20 records and then dynamically loads more via a pager, is that you'd have to separately track and store which values had been checked (since the AJAX would literally throw away and reload the next 20 checkbox values). By contrast, if it doesn't slow the page down to load all 2000 checkboxes as, say, 100 individual  sections behind the scenes, and then use your custom JS pager to show/hide the pages, your user could check and uncheck while paging and all the values would be remembered. (It's an often overlooked feature of HTML forms that they retain their field values even when hidden via CSS, which can be super helpful when you're aware of it).

I don't think a code snippet would be too useful here because this is a fairly open-ended problem, but the basic process would be:

1. Use `hook_form_alter()` to change the specific checkbox group field(s). Specifically, you would use markup to add the paginator controls after running the database query to retrieve the results and determine the number of pages.
2. Also as part of using `hook_form_alter()`, you would loop a page at a time and generate all 100 (or whatever number) pages of checkbox options, setting all but the first page to `display:none` in the `<div>` tags surrounding the checkbox options.
3. Create JS or jQuery functions in your site's custom theme, or put the code into an `includes/` folder and load it dynamically through `hook_form_alter` (not elegant - I recommend always having a custom theme or sub-theme available). This function would listen for the link press and the current page and hide/show the proper CSS blocks.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could also create a JS-enabled page number field where you could type in a page number and hit Enter, or a search feature that would return individual results (more complex since now you'd have to be able to show/hide all individual records), and a check all/uncheck all feature for individual pages. Have fun!